# namespace called 'exception' leads to compile problems

Tags: c++, exception, namespaces

I have a problem with a namespace called "exception"

Let's consider following example header:

```
#include <exception>

namespace exception
{
  struct MyException : public std::exception
  {};
}


struct AnotherException : public exception::MyException
{
    AnotherException() : exception::MyException() { }
};
```

This header does not compile with following error:

```
    namespacetest.hpp: In constructor 'AnotherException::AnotherException()':
    namespacetest.hpp:12:48: error: expected class-name before '(' token
    namespacetest.hpp:12:48: error: expected '{' before '(' token
```

There are two solutions for this:

1) qualify namespace with "::" in line 12

```
AnotherException() : ::exception::MyException() { }
```

2) Rename namespace to e.g. "exceptional"

What is the reason, that the namespace "exceptions" leads to confusion? I know that there is a class std::exception. Does this cause the trouble?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I know that there is a class `std::exception`. Does this cause the trouble?

Yes. Within `std::exception`, the unqualified name `exception` is the *injected class name*. This is inherited so, within your class, an unqualified `exception` refers to that, not your namespace.

Answer (score 10):

+1 to @Mike Seymour's answer! As a supplement, there are better ways than your current solution to prevent the ambiguity:

Just use `MyException`, without any namespace qualification:

```
struct AnotherException : public exception::MyException
{
    AnotherException() : MyException() { }
};
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/333bff895967a405)

Or use C++11's inherited constructors feature:

```
struct AnotherException : public exception::MyException
{
    using MyException::MyException;
};
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00ad54747df25ebd)